# CSS footer alignment ran in FF and IE

Tags: html, css, css-float

My site is at http://idezain.com/staging/minimaos , the footer for the main page looks good in Chrome, IE and FF. 
However if I clicked into one of the subpages, example http://idezain.com/staging/minimaos/category/accessories/ , the footer looks OK in Chrome but not in IE and FF.

Is there anyway I can detect what went wrong? I tried to check the sidebar, the footer and the page but I must have missed out something. 
Any headstart or advice appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `#Footer`, remove `margin-top: -13px`.

Doing that fixes the display of the footer in both  IE and Firefox.

Something unrelated that I noticed, in `style.css`, you have this line:

```
body {  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  font-size: 0.8em    height: 100%;   margin:0px; overflow-x: hidden; }
```

There is a semi-colon `;` missing after `0.8em`. You possibly want to get rid of `font-size: 0.8em` and `height: 100%`, I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi thirtydot. Thanks for your reply! I removed the margin top and it works. Thanks so  much,  I didn't realize that makes such a big difference :D